# Display Thumbnails Description with Multiple Post Thumbnails

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've added multiple featured images to my wordpress site using the multiple post thumbnail plugin.  I'm trying to display them all underneath the content with their descriptions. I can do it for the main featured image no problem.  I can display the rest of the featured images no problem, but whenever I try to add description by it's the page description not the image description.

This is how I added the main image and description.

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'product-thumbnail' ); 
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; ?>
```

The remaining images are added as such:

```
<?php MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-    
image', NULL,  'product-thumbnail');
?>
```

And so forth (third, fourth)..

Can somebody help with how to add the descriptions for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

To display your post thumbnail with its caption, simply paste the following code inside the loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?>
```

You can also display entire image description by adding this code inside the post loop:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();
echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; ?>
```

the above codes for single images if you use multiple images use this code below

```
<?php
        $the_post_images = get_children( array(
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type'=> 'image'
        ) );

    foreach ($the_post_images as $the_post_image) {
        // SHOW FEATURED IMAGE TITLES
        echo get_the_title( $the_post_image->ID );
        //SHOW IMAGE DESCRIPTION OR CAPTIONS
        echo apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $the_post_image->post_excerpt );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Right, I did do that for the main image, as you will see that exact code in my question, but I'm using multiple featured images with the plugin multiple post thumbnails.  It's adding the additional thumbnail descriptions I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: also i use the LightGalley slider i created this code for showing the featured images title and image description. show the additional code above

Answer (score 0):

To get image, its caption in multiple post thumbnails,

`

```
  echo $secondimgPath =  MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_url( get_post_type(), 'second-featured-image', NULL);

  echo $secondimgIdAttachment = abcd_get_attachment_id_by_url($secondimgPath);

  $size = array( 854,395, 'bfi_thumb' => true, 'quality' => 100);

  echo $secondLargeImage[0] = wp_get_attachment_image( $secondimgIdAttachment,$size );

  echo get_post( $secondimgIdAttachment )->post_excerpt;
```

endif; ?>`

In functions.php, use the following -

```
function abcd_get_attachment_id_by_url( $url ) {
// Split the $url into two parts with the wp-content directory as the separator
$parsed_url  = explode( parse_url( WP_CONTENT_URL, PHP_URL_PATH ), $url );
// Get the host of the current site and the host of the $url, ignoring www
$this_host = str_ireplace( 'www.', '', parse_url( home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) );
$file_host = str_ireplace( 'www.', '', parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_HOST ) );
// Return nothing if there aren't any $url parts or if the current host and $url host do not match
if ( ! isset( $parsed_url[1] ) || empty( $parsed_url[1] ) || ( $this_host != $file_host ) ) {
    return;
}
// Now we're going to quickly search the DB for any attachment GUID with a partial path match
// Example: /uploads/2013/05/test-image.jpg
global $wpdb;
$attachment = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE guid RLIKE %s;", $parsed_url[1] ) );
// Returns null if no attachment is found
return $attachment[0];
```

}